# How to i loop the Xelement class and get the below result

Tags: c#, xml

Using a loop with xelement class in C# i would like to get the below result!

```
<data>

 <description>Cities that I have recently visited.</description>

 <cities>
  <city id="1">
   <name>Chicago1</name>
   <state>IN1</state>
  </city>

  <city id="2">
   <name>Chicago2</name>
   <state>IN2</state>
  </city>

  <city id="3">
   <name>Chicago3</name>
   <state>IN3</state>
  </city>

 </cities>

 </data>
```

This is the code i have tried so far! any help?? i need to use a loop and get the above values..The loop i used is commented..

```
namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xmlDataStore = new XElement("data",
            new XElement("cities",

    new XElement("city", new XAttribute("id", "1")),
    new XElement("city", "Colombo"),
    new XElement("name", "lname"),
    new XElement("state", "0772569984")

    )
            )
                ;

            //var list = from x in XElement.ReadFrom(xmlDataStore).Element("Node").Elements() 
            //select new
            //{
            //   Name = x.Name,
            //   Value = (string)x
            //};


            Console.WriteLine(xmlDataStore);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }


    }
}
```

What i get...

```
<cities>
  <city id="1">
   <name>Chicago1</name>
   <state>IN1</state>
  </city>
  </cities>
```

What i want...

```
<data>

 <description>Cities that I have recently visited.</description>

 <cities>
  <city id="1">
   <name>Chicago1</name>
   <state>IN1</state>
  </city>

  <city id="2">
   <name>Chicago2</name>
   <state>IN2</state>
  </city>

  <city id="3">
   <name>Chicago3</name>
   <state>IN3</state>
  </city>

 </cities>

 </data>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that formatting was purposeful, but it doesn't add readability if that's what you're aiming for.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `xmlDataStore.ToString()` suffice? Or do you really want blank lines between (some) elements? Or what is the exact problem you want to solve?

Comment: Sorry for that! Its formatted now!

Comment: I just want to display the above result! as mentioned above!

Comment: Okay, let me put it differently. What do you *get* and how does it differ from what you *want*?

Comment: Ok updated it in the question on what i get and what i want to get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I still don't exactly know what the real problem is, so let's start with this:

```
private static void citiesXml()
{
  const string desc = "Cities that I have recently visited.";

  // set up a list of all the different cities
  var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
  list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chicago1", "IN1"));
  list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chicago2", "IN2"));
  list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chicago3", "IN3"));

  var xmlDataStore = new XElement("data", new XElement("description", desc));
  var xmlCities = new XElement("cities");

  // loop through the list of cities and create a XElement for each single one
  for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
  {
    xmlCities.Add(new XElement("city", 
        new XAttribute("id", i + 1), 
        new XElement("name", list[i].Item1), 
        new XElement("state", list[i].Item2)));
  }

  // add the cities to the data store object
  xmlDataStore.Add(xmlCities);

  Console.WriteLine(xmlDataStore);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This will print:

```
<data>
  <description>Cities that I have recently visited.</description>
  <cities>
    <city id="1">
      <name>Chicago1</name>
      <state>IN1</state>
    </city>
    <city id="2">
      <name>Chicago2</name>
      <state>IN2</state>
    </city>
    <city id="3">
      <name>Chicago3</name>
      <state>IN3</state>
    </city>
  </cities>
</data>
```

So as far as I see it, the only difference is that there are no blank lines between cities. Are the missing blank lines the problem?

Comment: Thanks Man! I dont know What was wrong! but this worked! i have to check it out!

Comment: `static void Main(string[] args) { citiesXml(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Check by Descendants

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Xml File Path"); //save that xml in "C:\test.xml "
IEnumerable<XElement> xEle = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//cities");
   if(xEle !=null)
    {
      foreach(XElement xE in  Xelement.Descendants())
        {
            // here you will get everything ......
         }
     }
```

you can loop through